# How to Create Multilevel Javascript model from Form data

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I have a class with certain properties as string and int.
One of the properties is another class.

For example

```
 public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public ProductDetails Details { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDetails 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Location{ get; set; }
    public int Supplier{ get; set; }
}
```

I use WebAPI for CRUD operations. I have a form where I enter the new product. The form has all the fields for Name,Price etc. I need the data from form to be posted via Ajax instead of the regular submit method. I accomplish it by using

```
function addnew(frm) {
            var o = {};
            var a = frm.serializeArray();
            $.each(a, function () {
                if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                    if (!o[this.name].push) {
                        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                    }
                    o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                } else {
                    o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: uri,
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify(o),
                statusCode: {
                    201 : function (data) { //created
                        showAllItems();
                    }
                }
            })
            .fail(function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                alert(err);
            });
        }
```

and posting it via JQuery Ajax. The object is showing in the controller's post method (where I would write Insert statement).

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostProduct(Product item)
{
}
```

But I would like to add the product details in the form.

How can I specify the details for the ProductDetails in the form and get it in the controller ?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="frm">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="productName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Product Name:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name" id="productName">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="price" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Price:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Price" id="price">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="description" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Category:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Category" id="description">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="location" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Location:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Location.LocationName" id="location">
    </div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-large btn-success pull-right" onclick="addnew('frm')" style="margin-right:10px;" />
```

somebody please help.... Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So in your controller method `PostProduct` you are getting your model `item` filled as of now? I mean the values you entered there are coming in your controller method right??

Comment: Yes. The values are all coming in the controller action.

Comment: So now you want to save it!! how you wanna achieve it!! `Entity Framework` or `SQL Stored Procedures`??

Comment: Not save right now. I want the product details too be available in the controller. Now that property becomes null. How can I specify inputs for the details in the form so that It too comes in ? For eg. ProductDetails.Location , Supplier etc . ?

Comment: Oh `Product details` inside `products` is coming as null??

Comment: Exactly. If I am posting the form using submit() then everything is alright. I want to use $.Ajax() though...

Comment: Then I feel you might need to follow some other approach!! Can you post your html too??

Comment: My Html has been added.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I got it working.

name the input with your class.property name. In my case, Location.LocationName

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Location.LocationName" id="location">
```

and in script, remove the 'contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' or whatever.

```
$.ajax({
    url: uri,
    type: 'post',
    data: myform.serialize(),
    statusCode: {
        201 : function (data) { //created
        loaditems();
        }
    }
})
```

In the controller,

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostProduct(Product model)
{
    products.Add(new Product { Id = ... });
    var response = Request.CreateResponse<Product>(HttpStatusCode.Created, model);
    return response;
}
```

Now the product is showing with all data supplied in the form.

Comment: Glad you got it!! Happy Coding!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try as below:

```
function addnew(frm) {
   var formID='#' + frm;
   var ProductDetails:{
          Location:$(formID+'.location').val(), 
          Supplier://Fill the supplier value. Couldn't find in your html!
   };

   var name=$(formID+'#productName').val();
   var category=$(formID+'#description').val();
   var price = $(formID+'#price').val();

   var item={'Name':name,'Category':category,'Price':price,'Details':ProductDetails};

   $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        statusCode: {
              201 : function (data) { //created
                    showAllItems();
              }
        }
     })
     .fail(function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
         alert(err);
     });
}
```